# Problems installing php-curl 5.6 in lamp mattrayner/lamp container:0.2.0

Tags: php

I have an error in my php application which returns the following error:
PHP Fatal error: Call to undefined function Classes_curl_init() in /app/cms/Classes/Classes/Utils.php on line 182, referer: http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/cms/index.php

The php version is 5.6 and I think the problem is that I don't have the php5.6-curl module installed.

The operating system version is:
Description: Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS
Release: 16.04
Codename: xenial

When I try to install php5.6-curl (apt install php5.6-curl)
I get back
Unable to locate package php5.6-curl
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'php5.6-curl'.
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'php5.6-curl'

I added the repositories : add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
But it remains the same.

Comment: `undefined function Classesl_curl_init()` - What is `Classesl_curl_init()`? It's not any standard function from the cURL extension.

Comment: On most English keyboards the letter "L" and the semicolon are right next to each. My guess is that you have a typo and `Classesl_curl_init()` is really `Classes;_curl_init()`, or something similar to that.